# Issue with element.html() in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I have a directive and in the linkFunction I am able to set the scope to a certain value by using attributes["attribute-value"]. I was expecting element.html() to provide the inner html of the directive.

```
    .directive("sfGroupbar", function () {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.text = element.html();
        scope.attr = attributes["text"];
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "controls/groupbar.html",
        link: linkFunction,
        scope: {}
    };
```

In my view, I am using the directive like so...

```
<sf-groupbar warning="50" error="80" text="Web Server">Some Text</sf-groupbar>
```

In groupbar.html, I am using the code like so...

```
<div ng-controller="groupbarController">
{{text}} <br />
{{attr}}
</div>
```

I was expecting to see "Some Text" and "Web Server" as output. I am getting only Web Server as output, and instead of "Some Text", I am getting the following as output...

```
<div ng-controller="groupbarController">
{{text}} <br />
{{attr}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `transclude` property of the directive to `true` and have to include `ng-transclude` attribute inside the `template` or `templateurl` 's HTML element to make innerHTML of the directive to render.

Here is the working plunker based on your code,

http://embed.plnkr.co/sXoLPxeFA21fxzzeAcVs/preview

Hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `text` and the other attributes in your scope definition like so

`scope { text : '=' }` and also you might wanna add `transclude` option to `true` to try and get the text inside your directive.
I'm sure you'll be interested to look at this part of the documentation
[Directive to manipulate the DOM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)